# Save & Retrieve Numpy Array From String

Tags: python, numpy

I would like to convert a multi-dimensional Numpy array into a string and, later, convert that string back into an equivalent Numpy array.

I do not want to save the Numpy array to a file (e.g. via the `savetxt` and `loadtxt` interface).

Is this possible?

Answer (score 16):

You could use [np.tostring](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.tostring.html) and [np.fromstring](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fromstring.html):

```
In [138]: x = np.arange(12).reshape(3,4)

In [139]: x.tostring()
Out[139]: '\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x03\x00\x00\x00\x04\x00\x00\x00\x05\x00\x00\x00\x06\x00\x00\x00\x07\x00\x00\x00\x08\x00\x00\x00\t\x00\x00\x00\n\x00\x00\x00\x0b\x00\x00\x00'

In [140]: np.fromstring(x.tostring(), dtype=x.dtype).reshape(x.shape)
Out[140]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11]])
```

Note that the string returned by `tostring` does not save the dtype nor the shape of the original array. You have to re-supply those yourself.

---

Another option is to use [np.save](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.save.html) or [np.savez](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savez.html) or [np.savez_compressed](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savez_compressed.html) to write to a `io.BytesIO` object (instead of a file):

```
import numpy as np
import io

x = np.arange(12).reshape(3,4)
output = io.BytesIO()
np.savez(output, x=x)
```

The string is given by

```
content = output.getvalue()
```

And given the string, you can load it back into an array using `np.load`:

```
data = np.load(io.BytesIO(content))
x = data['x']
```

This method stores the dtype and shape as well.

For large arrays, `np.savez_compressed` will give you the smallest string.

---

Similarly, you could use [np.savetxt](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html) and `np.loadtxt`:

```
import numpy as np
import io

x = np.arange(12).reshape(3,4)
output = io.BytesIO()
np.savetxt(output, x)
content = output.getvalue()
# '0.000000000000000000e+00 1.000000000000000000e+00 2.000000000000000000e+00 3.000000000000000000e+00\n4.000000000000000000e+00 5.000000000000000000e+00 6.000000000000000000e+00 7.000000000000000000e+00\n8.000000000000000000e+00 9.000000000000000000e+00 1.000000000000000000e+01 1.100000000000000000e+01\n'

x = np.loadtxt(io.BytesIO(content))
print(x)
```

---

Summary:

- `tostring` gives you the underlying data as a string, with no dtype or
  shape
- `save` is like `tostring` except it also saves dtype and shape (.npy format)
- `savez` saves the array in npz format (uncompressed)
- `savez_compressed` saves the array in compressed npz format
- `savetxt` formats the array in a humanly readable format

Comment: After extracting a chip a.k.a face area(`ndarray`) from image(`ndarray`), I saved as a column in a csv file using csv.writer(). This chip has been stored as a string whose `dtype` is unknown. Now, I am trying to read that string and convert to numpy array so that I can save the chip to the disk using cv2.imwrite() . Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to save the `dtype` as well you can also use the `pickle` module from python.

```
import pickle
import numpy as np

a = np.ones(4)
string = pickle.dumps(a)
pickle.loads(string)
```

Answer (score 1):

np.tostring and np.fromstring does NOT work anymore. They use np.tobyte but it parses the np.array as bytes and not string. To do that use ast.literal_eval.

if elements of lists are 2D float. ast.literal_eval() cannot handle a lot very complex list of list of nested list while retrieving back.

Therefore, it is better to parse list of list as dict and dump the string.

while loading a saved dump, ast.literal_eval() handles dict as strings in a better way. convert the string to dict and then dict to list of list

```
k = np.array([[[0.09898942, 0.22804536],[0.06109612, 0.19022354],[0.93369348, 0.53521671],[0.64630094, 0.28553219]],[[0.94503154, 0.82639528],[0.07503319, 0.80149062],[0.1234832 , 0.44657691],[0.7781163 , 0.63538195]]])

d = dict(enumerate(k.flatten(), 1))
d = str(d) ## dump as string  (pickle and other packages parse the dump as bytes)

m = ast.literal_eval(d) ### convert the dict as str to  dict

m = np.fromiter(m.values(), dtype=float) ## convert m to nparray
```

Answer (score 0):

I use JSON to do that:

**1. Encode to JSON**
The first step is to encode it to JSON:

```
import json
import numpy as np
np_array = np.array(
      [[[0.2123842 , 0.45560746, 0.23575005, 0.40605248],
        [0.98393952, 0.03679023, 0.6192098 , 0.00547201],
        [0.13259942, 0.69461942, 0.8781533 , 0.83025555]],

       [[0.8398132 , 0.98341709, 0.25296835, 0.84055815],
        [0.27619265, 0.55544911, 0.56615598, 0.058845  ],
        [0.76205113, 0.18001961, 0.68206229, 0.47252472]]])

json_array = json.dumps(np_array.tolist())
print("converted to: " + str(type(json_array)))
print("looks like:")
print(json_array)
```

Which results in this:

```
converted to: <class 'str'>
looks like:
[[[0.2123842, 0.45560746, 0.23575005, 0.40605248], [0.98393952, 0.03679023, 0.6192098, 0.00547201], [0.13259942, 0.69461942, 0.8781533, 0.83025555]], [[0.8398132, 0.98341709, 0.25296835, 0.84055815], [0.27619265, 0.55544911, 0.56615598, 0.058845], [0.76205113, 0.18001961, 0.68206229, 0.47252472]]]
```

**2. Decode back to Numpy**
To convert it back to a numpy array you can use:

```
list_from_json = json.loads(json_array)
np.array(list_from_json)
print("converted to: " + str(type(list_from_json)))
print("converted to: " + str(type(np.array(list_from_json))))
print(np.array(list_from_json))
```

Which give you:

```
converted to: <class 'list'>
converted to: <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
[[[0.2123842  0.45560746 0.23575005 0.40605248]
  [0.98393952 0.03679023 0.6192098  0.00547201]
  [0.13259942 0.69461942 0.8781533  0.83025555]]

 [[0.8398132  0.98341709 0.25296835 0.84055815]
  [0.27619265 0.55544911 0.56615598 0.058845  ]
  [0.76205113 0.18001961 0.68206229 0.47252472]]]
```

I like this method because the string is easy to read and, although for this case you didn't need storing it in a file or something, this can be done as well with this format.

Comment: Thanks! Note that this method can result in a loss of precision which might not work well for some applications.