# How does numpy handle mmap's over npz files?

Tags: numpy, gzip, mmap

I have a case where I would like to open a compressed numpy file using mmap mode, but can't seem to find any documentation about how it will work under the covers.  For example, will it decompress the archive in memory and then mmap it?  Will it decompress on the fly?

The documentation is absent for that configuration.

Comment: Are you talking about a file created with `np.savez`?  Or one created with `np.save` and then compressed?  `npz` files are loaded with `np.lib.npyio.NpzFile`.  Look at its code.

Comment: @hpaulj is correct, although [it is possible](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28281287/1461210) to extract a compressed array from an `.npz` archive to disk, then open the decompressed array in memmap mode. For on-the-fly compression and decompression you should really be looking at HDF5 ([PyTables](http://www.pytables.org) or [h5py](http://www.h5py.org)).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The short answer, based on looking at the code, is that archiving and compression, whether using `np.savez` or `gzip`, is not compatible with accessing files in `mmap_mode`.  It's not just a matter of how it is done, but whether it can be done at all.

Relevant bits in the `np.load` function

```
elif isinstance(file, gzip.GzipFile):
    fid = seek_gzip_factory(file)
...
    if magic.startswith(_ZIP_PREFIX):
        # zip-file (assume .npz)
        # Transfer file ownership to NpzFile
        tmp = own_fid 
        own_fid = False
        return NpzFile(fid, own_fid=tmp)
...
    if mmap_mode:
        return format.open_memmap(file, mode=mmap_mode)
```

Look at `np.lib.npyio.NpzFile`.  An `npz` file is a ZIP archive of `.npy` files.  It loads a dictionary(like) object, and only loads the individual variables (arrays) when you access them (e.g. `obj[key]).  There's no provision in its code for opening those individual files in`mmap_mode`.

It's pretty obvious that a file created with `np.savez` cannot be accessed as mmap.  The ZIP archiving and compression is not the same as the gzip compression addressed earlier in the `np.load`.

But what of a single array saved with `np.save` and then `gzipped`?  Note that `format.open_memmap` is called with `file`, not `fid` (which might be a gzip file).

More details on `open_memmap` in `np.lib.npyio.format`.  Its first test is that `file` must be a string, not an existing file fid.  It ends up delegating the work to `np.memmap`.  I don't see any provision in that function for `gzip`.

Comment: I recently came to the same conclusion by looking at the code. I was wondering if it would be hard to add this functionality. Given the fact that `numpy` developers are brilliant it would be surprinsing they did not even try. Do you have an opinion on that?

Comment: It was pointed out in another recent `npz` question, that you can go the other direction - create the compressed archive in memory (using StringIO).  In all these cases the `numpy` developers haven't done special `C` work - they use existing `python` modules (`mmap`, `zip`, etc).  `np.save` via `np.lib.npyio` is doing the speicalized array work, and even there it 'punts' to `pickle` when the going gets hard (e.g. saving dtype objects).

Comment: Not sure I understand your comment. It seems that opening the array decompress it in memory (it is probably on-the-fly decompression) so I guess one can create a `numpy.memap` object from that (the `bytes` variable).

Comment: Dig into the `np.lib.npyio` module, with side trips to `zipfile` and `mmap`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25837662/901925 demonstrates creating `savez` and `load` using a `io.BytesIO`, i.e. making an in memory compressed file.

Comment: Look particularly at `numpy.lib.npyio.NpzFile` to see how a variable is read from a  npz file.

Comment: Hum, I don't think one would want a memory compressed array. I was thinkink about simple creating a standard memory mapped array from the npz file.

Comment: the in memory compressed file isn't a solution to your problem, but understanding it might give insight into how compression, memory mapping and np.save interact.  But I doubt if there is a solution short of writing your own `zip` archiving/compressing code (in C).