# How to work with large dataset in pytorch

Tags: python, numpy, dataset, pytorch, large-data

I have a huge dataset that does not fit in memory (150G) and I'm looking for the best way to work with it in pytorch. The dataset is composed of several `.npz` files of 10k samples each. I tried to build a `Dataset` class

```
class MyDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, path):
        self.path = path
        self.files = os.listdir(self.path)
        self.file_length = {}
        for f in self.files:
            # Load file in as a nmap
            d = np.load(os.path.join(self.path, f), mmap_mode='r')
            self.file_length[f] = len(d['y'])

    def __len__(self):
        raise NotImplementedException()

    def __getitem__(self, idx):                
        # Find the file where idx belongs to
        count = 0
        f_key = ''
        local_idx = 0
        for k in self.file_length:
            if count < idx < count + self.file_length[k]:
                f_key = k
                local_idx = idx - count
                break
            else:
                count += self.file_length[k]
        # Open file as numpy.memmap
        d = np.load(os.path.join(self.path, f_key), mmap_mode='r')
        # Actually fetch the data
        X = np.expand_dims(d['X'][local_idx], axis=1)
        y = np.expand_dims((d['y'][local_idx] == 2).astype(np.float32), axis=1)
        return X, y
```

but when a sample is actually fetched, it takes more than 30s. It looks like the entire `.npz` is opened, stocked in RAM and it accessed the right index. 
How to be more efficient ?

**EDIT**

It appears to be a misunderstading of `.npz` files [see post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29082741/1141818), but is there a better approach ?

**SOLUTION PROPOSAL**

As proposed by @covariantmonkey, lmdb can be a good choice. For now, as the problem comes from `.npz` files and not `memmap`, I remodelled my dataset by splitting `.npz` packages files into several `.npy` files. I can now use the same logic where `memmap` makes all sense and is really fast (several ms to load a sample).

Answer (score 2):

How large are the individual `.npz` files? I was in similar predicament a month ago. Various [forum](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/whats-the-best-way-to-load-large-data/2977) posts, google searches later I went the [lmdb](https://lmdb.readthedocs.io/en/release/) route. Here is what I did

1. Chunk the large dataset into small enough files that I can fit in gpu — each of them is essentially my minibatch. I did not optimize for load time at this stage *just* memory.
2. create an lmdb index with `key = filename` and `data = np.savez_compressed(stff)`

`lmdb` takes care of the mmap for you and insanely fast to load.

Regards,
A

PS: `savez_compessed` requires a byte object so you can do something like

```py
output = io.BytesIO()
np.savez_compressed(output, x=your_np_data)
#cache output in lmdb
```