# Tensorflow format tf.Variable array as a string as input in another file

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow

I'm trying to convert the output of my python script that uses Tensorflow so that it can be passed as an input string to another file.

The output I get in the console is the following:

```
('Input from genesis: ', array([  7.07872450e-01,   3.32354023e+04,   5.85043602e+01,
         1.91101468e+00,   3.83828156e+05,   3.76164818e+01,
         2.11525035e+00,   3.73708814e-01,   9.32167812e+04], dtype=float32))
('Output from genesis: ', '[array([ 0.66993088,  1.        ,  1.        ,  0.87113315,  1.        ,\n        1.        ,  0.8923766 ,  0.59235483,  1.        ], dtype=float32)]')
Execution time: 2.57894515991 seconds
```

Is there a relatively easy way to format the array output as a string of the array? i.e. [ 1, 2, 3, 4]?

Bare in mind this is how it is inputted with the use of tf.Variable:

```
a = tf.Variable(tf.constant([random.uniform(0.,3.),random.uniform(0.,400000.),random.uniform(0.,128.),random.uniform(0.,3.),random.uniform(0.,400000.),random.uniform(0.,128.),random.uniform(0.,3.),random.uniform(0.,3.),random.uniform(0.,400000.)], dtype=tf.float32))
```

Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tensorflow is returning your results as a numpy array. Your question is simply, "how do I save a numpy array as a string." To which a few options exist. The top two answers on the google search below are `numpy.savetxt` and `numpy.array_str`, both sound like simple enough solutions to your problem. Following those two entries are a few stack overflow articles that go into more detail on converting numpy arrays to strings. I suspect you'll find everything you need there.

https://www.google.com/search?q=save+numpy+array+as+string&oq=save+numpy+array+as+string

[Save & Retrieve Numpy Array From String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25837641/save-retrieve-numpy-array-from-string)

Comment: Hi David, I'm not using numpy for this. The output is a tensor of shape [1,9]

Comment: The output of a call to `sess.run` is a numpy array. Tensors are objects only within the tensorflow environment. Did you call `sess.run`? If not then tensorflow did no computation for you. You must call `sess.run` to ask tensorflow to do a computation for you. If you have a tensor you only have an object that defines part of a computation graph. You have a meta-definition, not a value. `result = sess.run(mytensor)` will give you the value of that tensor.

Comment: As you can tell I'm fresh on the scene with tensorflow (and python in general haha) I just tried numpy.savetxt and it worked a treat dude. Thanks for your help, to my first question as well!!