# How to convert numpy arrays to bytes/BytesIO without copying?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, amazon-s3, boto3

I want to upload a numpy array to S3 using the boto3 package which expects a bytes object. I want to convert this numpy array to bytes but without any copying due to memory constraints. Things I tried that do not work because they create copies:

- [`numpy.ndarray.tobytes`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.tobytes.html), [`numpy.ndarray.tostring`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.tostring.html)
- `bytes(arr)`
- `io.BytesIO(arr)`
- `io.BytesIO(memoryview(arr))`

It seems numpy used to provide [`numpy.ndarray.getbuffer`](https://numpy.org/doc/1.13/reference/generated/numpy.getbuffer.html) but it was deprecated in later releases.

Is there a way to create a bytes view without copying?

Comment: I think https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25837641/save-retrieve-numpy-array-from-string/25837662#25837662 will help

Comment: Unfortunately, tostring is an alias to tobytes and also creates a copy of the original buffer.

Comment: I wonder how you check whether it gets copied? I also meant the other option where you save the array first and then read it back in bytes. Or the pickle answer

Comment: You can check by setting `arr[0]=something else` then check if the buffer changes too. I don't want to involve disk I/O either :)

Answer (score 2):

You can take advantage of the `ctypes` module to create a pointer to the data array, cast into byte form.

```
import ctypes

import numpy as np

# generate the test array 
size = 0x10
dtype = np.short
bsize = 2 # size of a single np.short in bytes, set for the data type you want to upload
arr = np.arange(size, dtype=dtype)

# create a pointer to the block of memory that the array lives in, cast to char type. Note that (size*bsize) _must_ be in parenthesis for the code to run correctly.
memory_block = (ctypes.c_char*(size*bsize)).from_address(arr.ctypes.data)
print(memory_block.raw)
# b'\x00\x00\x01\x00\x02\x00\x03\x00\x04\x00\x05\x00\x06\x00\x07\x00\x08\x00\t\x00\n\x00\x0b\x00\x0c\x00\r\x00\x0e\x00\x0f\x00'

# mutate the array and check the contents at the pointer
arr[0] = 255.
print(memory_block.raw)
# b'\xff\x00\x01\x00\x02\x00\x03\x00\x04\x00\x05\x00\x06\x00\x07\x00\x08\x00\t\x00\n\x00\x0b\x00\x0c\x00\r\x00\x0e\x00\x0f\x00'
```

This, at a minimum, seems to fulfill the test you put forward in the comments to the question. (i.e. if I mutate the array does my view on it change?).

There are a couple of things to notes here though. One, python bytes objects are immutable, meaning that if one is assigned to a variable, a copy is made.

```
y = memory_block.raw
print(y[:2])
# b'\xff\x00'
arr[0] = 127
print(y[:2])
# b'\xff\x00'
```

Two, `boto3` seems to want a File-like object, at least according to the source code for version 1.28.1. Calling `bio = BytesIO(memory_block.raw)` incurs a copy, which means that we're back to square one for uploading.

### An uploader class

The `ArrayUploader` class below implements a few basic IO methods (`read`, `seek`, `tell`). When `read` is called, the data *may still be copied* from the underlying memory blob, meaning that head room will still be limiting factor. However, if the size of the read is set, then only that much data is copied from the memory blob at a time. How `boto3` handles the size of its reads from the `IO` object I couldn't tell you.

```
import ctypes
import re
from io import IOBase

import numpy as np

class ArrayUploader(IOBase):
    # set this up as a child of IOBase because boto3 wants an object
    # with a read method. 
    def __init__(self, array):
        # get the number of bytes from the name of the data type
        # this is a kludge; make sure it works for your case
        dbits = re.search('\d+', str(np.dtype(array.dtype))).group(0)
        dbytes = int(dbits) // 8
        self.nbytes = array.size * dbytes
        self.bufferview = (ctypes.c_char*(self.nbytes)).from_address(array.ctypes.data)
        self._pos = 0

    def tell(self):
        return self._pos

    def seek(self, pos):
        self._pos = pos

    def read(self, size=-1):
        if size == -1:
            return self.bufferview.raw[self._pos:]
        old = self._pos
        self._pos += size
        return self.bufferview.raw[old:self._pos]
    

# generate the test array 
size = 0x10
dtype = np.short
arr = np.arange(size, dtype=dtype)

# initialize our uploader object
arrayuploader = ArrayUploader(arr)

# read some data out
print(x:=arrayuploader.read(8))
# b'\x00\x00\x01\x00\x02\x00\x03\x00'

# mutate the array, reread the same data
arr[0] = 127
arrayuploader.seek(0)
print(y:=arrayuploader.read(8))
# b'\x7f\x00\x01\x00\x02\x00\x03\x00'

# has x changed with the original array?
print(x == y)
# False
```